# How to extract release year from IMDB data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: imdb, beautifulsoup

I have been doing a simple problem of extracting data from this [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012) website, but because I could not understand the common way of doing this problem I found my own way and got stuck.

I am trying to get just name and release year the html code looks like this :

```
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="b">
        <h3 class="c"><span class="d">1</span> <a href="link%20here">name of
        movie</a> <span class="e">release year</span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I am done with the name extraction but I **can't** extract the year of release, please help

### My Code:

```
soup  = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
item = soup.find_all("div" , {"class" : "a"})
for i in item:
    title = i.find("div" , {"class" : "b"}).a
    release_year = i.find("div" , {"class" : "b"}.span
print(title.get_text() , release_year.get_text())
```

The output is coming as:

> (name of the movie , '1)

I want the output as

> (name of the movie , 1990 )

Answer (score 0):

The `release_year = i.find("div" , {"class" : "b"}.span` would result into `release_year` pointing to the first span inside the result header. The first span is the search result number and not a release year.

Instead, find by the class attribute values:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

search_results = soup.find_all("div", class_="lister-item-content")
for result in search_results:
    header = result.find("h3", class_="lister-item-header")

    title = header.a
    release_year = header.find(class_="lister-item-year")
    print(title.get_text(), release_year.get_text().strip("()"))
```

Prints:

```
(u'The Shawshank Redemption', u'1994')
(u'The Dark Knight', u'2008')
...
(u"One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", u'1975')
(u'The Truman Show', u'1998')
```